# Having conditionals for a Lua DSL?

Tags: lua, conditional-statements, dsl

I'm trying to build a small DSL in Lua with conditionals.

```
x = '0'
function start ()
    return function () end
end

function set_x (v)
    x = v
    return function () end
end

function if_x (v)
    if x == v then
        print ("x = ", v)
    else
        print ("x != ", v)
    end
    return function () end
end

-- DSL here
start {
    set_x '10',
    if_x '10' { print ('x is 10') },
    if_x '20' { print ('x is 20') }
}
```

Output is:

```
x =     10
x is 10
x !=    20
x is 20
```

How to implement conditionals in an elegant way so that `x is 20` is not printed?  I couldn't make that without setting a global variable in `set_x` and checking it within `if_x`, but this looks ugly.

Any clue?

Thanks!

Comment: And oh, BTW, what you have is typically called **E**DSL (embedded DSL), because it uses existing language constructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look at what your EDSL looks like to Lua; let's dissect the problematic statement

```
if_x '20' { print ('x is 20') }
```

We can rewrite it using "regular" syntax as such:

```
if_x('20')({ 1 = print('x is 20') })
```

I've added `1 =` to showcase the problematic part; construction of the array requires evaluation of the print statement *regardless* of your condition.

In order to make it to work, you actually need a lambda:

```
start {
    set_x '10',
    if_x '10' { function() print ('x is 10') end },
    if_x '20' { function() print ('x is 20') end }
}
```

Which can then be conditionally called:

```
function if_x (v)
    if x == v then
        print ("x = ", v)
        return function (block) block[1]() end
    else
        print ("x != ", v)
        return function () end
    end 
end
```

Not as pretty, but I don't think you can get rid of that, because any expression not wrapped with a lambda needs to execute. You could try playing with the conditional operator's short-circuit behaviour, but then you can't pass the code further, because it will always get evaluated at function borders.

[<kbd>**See Live on Ideone**</kbd>](https://ideone.com/62fNGm)

Answer (score 4):

e.g.

```
x = '10'

function if_x (v)
  if x == v then
    return function (s)
      assert(loadstring(s))()
    end
  end
  return function() end
end

if_x '10' [[print('x is 10')]]
if_x '20' [[print('x is 20')]]
```

Comment: To elaborate: `[[x]]` is alternate syntax for `"x"` in Lua. So the `print...` lines are actually strings being conditionally fed to the Lua parser at runtime. That's how this answer solves the problem of the evaluation: it's a string that gets passed to `if_x` not a function or a result of an expression. Good one! :)